# GlowPadView class could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a GlowPadView (https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView/) in my layout's XML but I get the following error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.fima.glowpadview.GlowPadView (Open Class, Show Error Log) See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details. Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must specify at least one target drawable
    at com.fima.glowpadview.GlowPadView.<init>(GlowPadView.java:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

This is the code I wrote in XML:

```
<com.fima.glowpadview.GlowPadView
        android:id="@+id/glow_pad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/glowpadview_margin_bottom"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        glowpad:directionDescriptions="@array/snooze_dismiss_direction_descriptions"
        glowpad:feedbackCount="1"
        glowpad:glowRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_glow_radius"
        glowpad:handleDrawable="@drawable/ic_alarm_alert_touch_handle"
        glowpad:innerRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_inner_radius"
        glowpad:outerRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_target_placement_radius"
        glowpad:outerRingDrawable="@drawable/ic_alarm_alert_outerring"
        glowpad:pointDrawable="@drawable/ic_lockscreen_glowdot"
        glowpad:snapMargin="@dimen/glowpadview_snap_margin"
        glowpad:targetDescriptions="@array/snooze_dismiss_descriptions"
        glowpad:targetDrawables="@array/snooze_dismiss_drawables"
        glowpad:vibrationDuration="20" />
```

I imported the project and added it to my build path as well in Android -> Library.

Comment: Is this happening only in Eclipse's graphical layout editor? I wouldn't consider this a big problem unless it's also not running on a device/emulator.

Comment: @A--C: Well, I can't compile it unless the error gets fixed.

Comment: If it won't let you run the code, the problem is most likely somewhere else. I cloned the repo, and yes, the graphical editor doesn't work, but I am able to run the application.

Comment: Please post your `@array/snooze_dismiss_drawables` definition, and confirm that all drawables referenced in it actually exist.